# python error with upload file ftp 226

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

When i'm try a upload file with my script in python, app reslut a bad "226 0 matches total"

Sometimes app upload sometimes not

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect(ftp_host)
ftp.login(ftp_user, ftp_password)
ftp.cwd("./")
print "Sciezka", ftp.pwd()
print "Wgrywam"
fullname = newfile
name = os.path.split(fullname)[1]
f = open(fullname, "rb")
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + name, f)
f.close()
print "OK"
print "Files:"
print ftp.retrlines("LIST")
ftp.quit()
```

Comment: `226 0` and `226 1` check host answer before closing ftp connection.

Comment: Successfully connection to ftp